# How to unify the end lines between Visual Studio 2015 and Xamarin Studio?

Tags: git, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, uwp

I m doing a Xamarin project using Xamarin Studio for the iOS and Android version and Visual Studio for the UWP version. When I move the project from Windows to Mac or from Mac to Windows, git is showing me differences in the end of lines, so I wan't to unify the treatment for the ends of lines.
Maybe there is a global configuration for the two IDE ?

Comment: You can set Xamarin Studio to automatically convert line endings in the setting: Xamarin Studio > Preferences > Text Editor > General > Line Ending Conversion. That's about as helpful as I can be on this subject :)

Answer (score 1):

You should follow simple rules:

1. Only use Git to share source files between computers. Avoid sending files using other means. You could set up new branches for “private” code (not tested yet etc.).
2. Set up Git to handle line endings for a multi-platform project. It will keep your files in the native format on each supported platform.

   ```
   # Mac and other Unix-like systems
   git config --global core.autocrlf input

   # Windows
   git config --global core.autocrlf true
   ```

More info: https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration